# ActionMailer Template stored in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

The question here is

**"Is it bad practice to store email templates in DB and render?"**

I know this is what people don't apply. (Usually it's rendered from `.erb` and good to go, and it should be avoided from accessing DB as much as possible.)

But there are business requirements below

- For business reasons, I need to have the history of each email. (Who's got sent, what title and bodies are sent.)

Third party Transaction Email service provider can store the histories, but I need to store them locally.

So I'm thinking about storing templates within DB, and render it, so that I can track what email was sent even templates change.

Any advices for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For business reasons, I need to have the history for each emails.
>   (Who's got sent, what title and bodies are sent.)

You can go with the following approach:

1. create the db-backed AR model, like `EmailsHistory`
2. create instance of `EmailsHistory`  each time the email is coming out.

---

```
## Columns:
#  * title
#  * recipient
#  * body
#  * anything else
#
class EmailsHistory
end
```

Then, at the moment of email sending just add a row to `emails_history` table with all the columns you need to have info of.

Comment: Thank you! I'm also little worried about I/O when sending emails. It would be great if you could suggest the way to reduce I/O for db when applying your idea :)  Always appreciate your answer!

Comment: @Toshi this should not be a db-costly setup, but if you want you could use Sidekiq for processing both, sending email and writing to db. You can wrap the logic into a service and process it in background

Comment: I'm thinking parallel processing for sending emails, so it's would be complicated if I apply backend job. So I think I'll go for the your first suggestion :) Thanks!